# How to deal with keyboard layout broken when working in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard, fedora, gnome, keyboard-layout

I've installed latest Fedora-36 + Gnome-42 distro and got some strange issue with keyboard layouts.

Somehow VSCode and gnome conflicting and (i guess!) i get frequently overridden keyboard layout.

FYTK how my keyboard layout looks like after some work:
[image]

Idk if this is ok for keyboard layout to look this way, but i still have an issue of periodic hard VS Code freezes.

Also, sometimes, i get a problem of static keyboard layout, that even after manual switching (by hotkeys) to another, my layout continue to be the same. To fix this i need to do a lot of tries of win+space (my hotkey) and after 20-40 repeats it comes back to normal.
Interesting fact: it does not depends on time. I could go afk for some time and nothing changes.

Without VSCode everything seems to work fine.

System:

- Fedora: 5.17.14-300.fc36.x86_64
- Gnome: 42.2
- VSCode: code-1.68.1-1655263151.el7.x86_64.rpm

Before writing question i've tried to install different verisons of VSCode, like insiders 1.69 or flatpak one. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code freezing was a nvidia issue. Keyboard layout stopped to be static after driver fix.

I guess overriding was just my imagination.